# Trouble adjusting image height for landscape and portrait images

Tags: css

I'm creating a responsive version of an existing site for an estate agency. Each property has a gallery of images, which display nicely when the images are landscape. The problem is when they are portrait.

In the original code the image sizes are defined as:

```
#gallery-images {
  height: 577px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 828px;
}
```

I'm overwriting this (with a media query) so it becomes

```
#gallery-images {
  height: 205px !important;
  left: 1px;
  width: 290px;
  }
```

However, this means that the portrait images are cropped from the top and results in a less than ideal display - [see here for example](http://23.co.uk/dev/tmh/lettings-list/dkh-dog-kennel-hill.html).

If I set `height:auto` and `overflow:visible` the portrait images display okay, but there are negative consequences for the page height. In essence, the gallery nav stays in position but there's lots of white space above when landscape images are shown again.

One option is to move the gallery nav above the images and suffer the white space below but I wonder if there's another solution I haven't thought of. I'm limited as to the non-CSS changes I can make but perhaps could persuade the client to add something if a script would provide a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to you if you want to display overflow or not but I think you are looking for declaring a min-width...if you leave the height off then the image will scale proportionally.

Comment: Min-width won't solve the problem I'm afraid, it's the height I'm having trouble with. 

Thinking about it some more, what I'd like is a way of constraining the height without cropping images from the top.

Comment: Try checking this out : http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/ or doing a google search for responsive images